# Reversed JPA results for @OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I will split my problem into 3 sections:

1. JPA Entities
2. Current database setup
3. The problem

## 1. JPA Entities

### Foo

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;
    
    // ... other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fooer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Bar> barInfo = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fooing", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Bar> baringInfo = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

### Bar

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
public class Bar {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fooer_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false,
                foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "bar_fooer_id_fkey"))
    private Foo fooer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fooing_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false,
                foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "bar_fooing_id_fkey"))
    private Foo fooing;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "baz_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false,
                foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "bar_baz_id_fkey"))
    private Baz baz;
}
```

### Baz

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "baz")
public class Baz {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;
    
    // ... other fields
}
```

## 2. Current database setup

### DDL

```sql
CREATE TABLE some_schema.bar
(
    id        int8 GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 START 1 CACHE 1 NO CYCLE) NOT NULL,
    fooer_id  int8 NOT NULL,
    fooing_id int8 NOT NULL,
    baz_id    int8 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT bar_id_key UNIQUE (id),
    CONSTRAINT bar_fooer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (fooer_id) REFERENCES some_schema.foo (id),
    CONSTRAINT bar_fooing_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (fooing_id) REFERENCES some_schema.foo (id),
    CONSTRAINT bar_baz_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (baz_id) REFERENCES some_schema.baz (id)
);
```

## 3. The problem

Let's say we have two entities of type `Foo` (John[id=111] and Alice[id=222]) and one entity of type `Baz` (Paperwork[id=999]). **John** wants to request help from **Alice** that relates to **Paperwork**. My current implementation of adding request explained above looks like this:

```java
final var john = getById(contextId); // fooing
final var alice = getById(id);       // fooer
final var paperwork = bazService.getBazById(bazId);

john.getBarInfo()
    .add(Bar.builder()
            .fooer(alice)
            .fooing(john)
            .baz(paperwork)
            .build());

fooRepository.save(john); // <-- Here john have barInfo with values set above and baringInfo empty which is what we want
```

Data in table `bar` looks like this:

| id | fooer_id | fooing_id | baz_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 222 | 111 | 999 |

Which from the perspective of current implementation and requirement looks okay. **But the problem lies in retrieving entity and entities of type `Foo`**.

**Expected** result by retrieving either by ID or whole list:

```json
{
  "John": {
    "barInfo": {
      "fooers": [
        {
          "foo_id": 222,
          "baz_id": 999
        }
      ],
      "fooing": []
    }
  },
  "Alice": {
    "barInfo": {
      "fooers": [],
      "fooing": [
        {
          "foo_id": 111,
          "baz_id": 999
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Actual** result:

```json
{
  "John": {
    "barInfo": {
      "fooers": [],
      "fooing": [
        {
          "foo_id": 111,
          "baz_id": 999
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Alice": {
    "barInfo": {
      "fooers": [
        {
          "foo_id": 222,
          "baz_id": 999
        }
      ],
      "fooing": []
    }
  }
}
```

> The data displayed above is pseudo-representation of entity `Foo` retrieved from Spring repository (not wrapped to other object)

The `fooing`/`fooers` seems to be reversed (I assume there is something wrong with my associations between entities) and I'm wondering if there is some flaw in my approach. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

---

Versions used in project:

- Spring Boot 3.2.2
- Java 17

Comment: You should try to remove code from `Bar` and keep retrieving the data from the database until you find the wrong configuration.

Comment: I've tried that but to no avail. What I've done as a temporary fix was moving from two fields `List` to one **transient** `List` that contains `BarInfo`. The `BarInfo` contains `@Column` annotations for `fooer_id`, `fooing_id` and `baz_id`. But this approach does not provide "easy" way to get required information by getters (no relation beacuse of `@Transient`) - I have to retrieve data manually via repository. I'm still trying to figure out better approach to my problem which would allow us to retrieve data via getters (using Hibernate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

All I had to do was reverse `mappedBy` parameters for `Foo`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;
    
    // ... other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fooing", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
                          ~~~~~~~~
    private List<Bar> barInfo = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fooer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
                          ~~~~~~~
    private List<Bar> baringInfo = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And in service related to adding request instead of adding to list of `barInfo` or `baringInfo`, we should have just saved new `Bar` and it will be associated with respective entities:

```java
final var john = getById(contextId); // fooing
final var alice = getById(id);       // fooer
final var paperwork = bazService.getBazById(bazId);
final var bar = Bar.builder()
                   .fooer(alice)
                   .fooing(john)
                   .baz(paperwork)
                   .build();
barRepository.save(bar);
```

Retrieving information about `Foo` gives expected result mentioned in my question.